# IOS 7 corrupted database

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios7

Our app has a process where we build a sqlite database and upload it to Amazon S3. When the app starts on a users phone it checks the version # of the database and if a newer one exists it downloads and replaces the sqlite database currently installed on the phone.

Since IOS 7 we have noticed that a lot of phones are getting a corrupted database error.

My instinct is telling me that it might have something to do with the default journaling mode for ios 7 and WAL journaling now being the default but have seen the same issue happen on IOS 6 when we generate the file using IOS 7.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Are you using Core Data or raw SQLite?

Comment: Which files do you upload? How do you synchronize the file accesses with any concurrent database accesses?

Comment: Wain we are using Core Data stack

Comment: CL, we upload the sqlite database itself. At the time the file is being uploaded replaced no other thread process is accessing it. We are doing it right when the app launches and before the DB itself is open by Core data.

Comment: Which file do you means with "the sqlite database itself"?

Comment: CL, 

The actual sqlite file CDCFF6AA-01EB-4C03-A2FB-8680909047FC/Documents/MobileShopper2.sqlite

Comment: Nov 26 18:28:19 MTVN-SQA-iPhone4S Ratings_Test[769] <Warning>: Core Data: annotation: -executeRequest: encountered exception = Fatal error.  The database at /var/mobile/Applications/57BCBC23-CA00-401B-A410-6B2FA2B1FC06/Documents/MobileShopper2.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed' with userInfo = {

    NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Applications/57BCBC23-CA00-401B-A410-6B2FA2B1FC06/Documents/MobileShopper2.sqlite";

    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 11;

}

Answer (score 1):

Two things I can think of: 1) There are some external files that are hanging around from the original DB that confuse SQLite. 2) When your app "starts" could your DB still be open (returning from background?).  If you're trying to replace an open DB with a new one, the file system may be rejecting your delete of an open file, then you try to write the new one on top, etc...

Otherwise, you could download the new DB separately, open it's contents and update the existing one from the contents -- a lot more work.

Comment: Owen, I have confirmed that the following files are all in the directory:

CDCFF6AA-01EB-4C03-A2FB-8680909047FC/Documents/MobileShopper2.sqlite
CDCFF6AA-01EB-4C03-A2FB-8680909047FC/Documents/MobileShopper2.sqlite-shm
CDCFF6AA-01EB-4C03-A2FB-8680909047FC/Documents/MobileShopper2.sqlite-wal

Comment: So when you blow away the database to replace it with a fresh one, do you blow away all the other files too?  Note that these files might still be open, and you may not be able to delete a file used by a process.

Comment: Now that you say it's a CoreData backend, there may be other issues as well.  Apple's CoreData persistent storage is proprietary.  You may be better off downloading the replacement data in some readable format, and importing it into your existing CoreData storage by deleting the existing records, and adding in the replacement records.  In other words, let CoreData deal with the database, and you send your replacement data to CoreData.